# Adding entries to Win + R

Tags: windows, batch-file, keyboard-shortcuts, runcommand

I created a program I would like to launch using the Run command (Win + R). How would I go about adding program paths to the Run command's current list of programs?

Some people have suggested using batch files, but I am still unsure where to place the batch file after it has been created. Any thoughts?

Comment: The question is vague. Consider illustrating it with some example(s).

Answer (score 1):

In Win+R dialog you don’t see a list of installed programs. That list contains programs that were recently launched through that dialog.

That list is kept in the following registry key:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RunMRU`
The format is obvious: `a`-`z` values are command lines, `MRUList` value is the sequence of `a`-`z` keys recently launched, in the order.

However, it’s completely undocumented and unsupported. If I were you, I wouldn’t mess with the data in that key because it’s Windows’ implementation details. Just place a shortcut to your program somewhere in `%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu`, and you’ll be able to start typing the name of your program after Win key, without the “R”.